# I am not able to post data with $http.post to springMVC controller(RESTfull service), both angular and controller working on different ports

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, ionic-framework, cors

**My angular code:**

```
     var user={id:null,username:'data',address:'',email:''};

$http.post("localhost:8080/Myservice/adduser",user).success(function(data) {
            alert("data gaya");
            alert(data);
        }).error(function(data1, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "nahi gaya"+headers+"config"+config);
        });
```

**Here is my Spring service mapping**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createUser1(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody User user) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
    System.out.println("Created a  User " + user.getUsername());
    String sss ="{\"employeeID\":\"101\"}";
  return sss;
}
```

**Here is my pojo class**

```
public class User {

private long id;

private String username;

private String address;

private String email;

public User(){
}

public User(long id, String username, String address, String email){
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

> **when ,I am making a post call without sending any data it is working fine but when i post data it is giving this error**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/adduser. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

**findings**

when I called my service using mozilla's RESTclient it gives the error

[image]

Any help would be very appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [CORS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html) on your controller method. Annotate the `createUser1` method with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain.com")` where we only allow `http://domain.com` to send cross-origin requests.

Or simply you can annotate with `@CrossOrigin` on your controller method or the class to enable CORS from all domains.

Some helpful links and documentation -

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/